# Linux Message Queue receive with particular mtype failed between two Process

Tags: linux, message-queue

send.c create a message queue and sends message with mtype 5

**send.c**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/ipc.h>
#include<sys/msg.h>
#include<string.h>
struct msgbuf
    {
    long mtype;
    char mtext[40];
    };
void main()
    {
    int key,id;
    struct msgbuf vara; 
    key = ftok("/usr", 65);
    id = msgget(key, IPC_CREAT|0666);
    vara.mtype=5;
    strcpy(vara.mtext,"hi");
    msgsnd(id,&vara, strlen(vara.mtext)+1, 0);
    perror("status:");
    printf("msg sent\n");
    }
```

receive.c is trying to receive message from message queue with mtype 5

**recieve.c**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/ipc.h>
#include<sys/msg.h>
#include<string.h>
#define MAXSIZE 128
struct msgbuf
    {
    long mtype;
    char mtext[40];
    };
void main()
    {
    int key;    int id;
    struct msgbuf vars;
    key = ftok("/usr", 65);
    id = msgget(key, IPC_CREAT|0666);
    msgrcv(id,&vars,MAXSIZE,5,0);
    perror("status ");
    printf("msg rcvd --> %s\n", vars.mtext);
    }
```

Im not able receive message with particular mtype mentioned in msgrcv function in receive.c  file however i able receive message if mtype set to 0

Comment: Works here. What is the type received?

Comment: @Prabhu it is not working in my system, it keeps on waiting to receive message with that particular message type(5)

Comment: Did the `send` succeed?

Comment: yes , even im able to recieve the message if mtype set  to 0